# Value of input type="number" always one off on Mousewheel

Tags: jquery, events, mousewheel

I have an input of `type="number"` where I want to get the numeric value of the input on any type of change. I'm using the `.on()` method to handle the change events. The types change events that I am concerned with are:

- Clicking the up and down arrows on the input field with the mouse
- Entering a number with the keyboard
- Using the up and down arrows on the keyboard
- Using the mouse wheel

Currently with the code I have, the first three types of changes get recorded correctly, but the `wheel` change is always one off the expected value.

**Question:**
Can somebody explain to me why the value of the input is incorrect on the mouse wheel change, but not on the other types of changes and how I could fix this?

```js
$("#elementId:input").on('keyup mouseup wheel', function () {
  var additionMemberCount = $('#elementId:input').val()
  console.log(additionMemberCount);          
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="elementId" min="4" placeholder="4+">
```

Comment: Hmm, it's correct when I use a Magic Mouse that has touch gestures. But if I use a Logitech mouse with a real wheel it's off by 1.

Comment: One off here. What brand mouse? Does it have any smooth scrolling features or software?

Comment: It's a `TeckNet M002` cordless optical mouse. The driver provider is Microsoft and the Driver Version is `10.0.18362.1`